# "Error: Error building ARM Config" when migrating from local to azurerm backend

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, azure-service-principal

I am using Terraform to create a storage container on Microsoft Azure to store remote state files. To create the storage container, I have wrote the appropriate terraform code and applied the infrastructure, using a local state file. The problem is when then add the azurerm backend to my main.tf to migrate the local state, I am getting the following error:

```
terraform init -reconfigure

Initializing the backend...
> ╷
Error: Error building ARM Config: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in $PATH.
```

I have the following environment variables set:

- ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- ARM_TENANT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
- ARM_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

And I am using input vars to handle the client_certificate_path and client_certificate_password.

When I `terraform init/plan/apply` using a local backend, everything works as expected:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.52.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_certificate_path     = var.client_certificate_path
  client_certificate_password = var.client_certificate_password
}
```

My expectation is that by adding the azurerm backend, I should be able to use `terraform init -migrate-state` to migrate the state information to the remote backend. Here is the code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.52.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "exampletfstate"
    storage_account_name = "exampletfstate"
    container_name       = "exampletfstate"
    key                  = "state.terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_certificate_path     = var.client_certificate_path
  client_certificate_password = var.client_certificate_password
}
```

and here is the result:

```
❯ terraform init -migrate-state

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Error building ARM Config: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in $PATH.
```

It feels like terraform isn't picking up the service principle credentials when using the azurerm backend, but I cannot put my finger on what is happening.

Terraform/Provider Versions:

```
❯ terraform --version
Terraform v1.4.5
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.52.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is configured in my terraform code.

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  //subscription_id = "xx3f"
  //tenant_id              = "xxx47"
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
    }

  }

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "resourcegroupname"
    storage_account_name = "remotestatestorage"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

You need to do **`az login`**

[image]

Login with the credentials and

Set subscription

**`az account set --subscription <desiredSubscriptionId>`**

[image]

With wrong tenant  you may face errors as :`Error building ARM Config: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version`
In that case run the below command to set correct tenant where proper permissions like contributor are given .

**`az login --tenant TENANT_ID`**

Then try to run **`terraform init`**

[image]

> terraform plan or terraform apply

I have v1.0.7 terraform version

**`terraform --version`**

```
Terraform v1.0.7
on windows_amd64
```

**providers.tf**

```
terraform {
   
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "=1.2.0"
    }

    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.2"
    }

    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "=3.1.2"
    }
  }
```

Also refer [Build Infrastructure - Terraform Azure Example | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/azure-get-started/azure-build)

**Reference :**
[Authenticate Terraform to Azure | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/authenticate-to-azure?tabs=bash)

Comment: Thank you for helping kavyaS. A dependency that I I failed to mention in my OP (apologise) is that the users of the code will not have access to az login or the azure console.

Answer (score 0):

I have this morning discovered the cause.

In order for terraform to read the tfstate from azure, it needs all credentials up front, including the cert path and password that I am declaring  in the provider settings. Terraform seems to pull state information before asking for missing input vars.

To unblock myself for now, I have written a bash wrapper around terraform so that the cert path/password are added as environment variables which terraform can read when it looks for the remote state files. This isn't my ideal solution as I need to manage the security of these vars by unsetting them after use etc.